# Find first column with empty cell in every third row using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

As the title says, I need to find the first column with an empty cell in every third row in my sheet.

It looks like this:

```
-----------
  ---------
    ------- 
     ------
```

I need to write data from another sheet into each (third) row. That part of the code is ok, I checked it. But, for some reason, this code doesn't work:

```
  For t = 5 To 500 Step 3
         u = 0
         For s = 5 To 500
            If IsEmpty(Cells(t, s)) And s > g And u = 0 Then
            g = s
            u = 1
            Exit For
            End If
         Next s
  Next t
```

Comment: I think there's only one _third row_ in a sheet. Are you sure you didn't mean to find _the first empty column in every third row of each sheet_? Or alternatively _the first empty column every three rows (i.e. in row 3, in row 6, in row 9 etc.)_?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I meant first column, in which the cell for every third row is empty

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear what your problem is, but this will find the first blank cell in every third row and change it to a value you assign it.

```
Sub firstBlankEveryThirdRow()
    For t = 5 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count Step 3
        Range("1:1").Offset(t - 1).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)(1).Value = "Insert Your Value Here"
    Next t
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but its not what i am trying to do. In integer g, i need to have number of first column that has blank cell at every third row. (5,g) (8,g) (11,g)... they are all blank

Comment: g = Range("1:1").Offset(t - 1).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)(1).column